# React - Parent not passing method to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've got a React/Firebase app.  I'm trying to make a button that uses a google login to firebase auth.

I've had the button working fine when rendered from `App.js` where the login method is.  When I try and call it from my login component nothing happens, no errors, just nothing

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Status from './status';
import Login from './login';
import Navigation from './navigation';
import { auth, provider } from '../firebase';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      authUser: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
      if (authUser) {
        this.setState({ authUser });
      } 
    });
  }

  login = () => {
    auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then( (result) => {
        const user = result.user;
        this.setState({
          authUser: user
        });
      })
      .catch( (err) => {
        console.log('Error Logging In', err);
      });
  }

  logout = () => {
    auth.signOut()
    .then(() => {
      this.setState({
        authUser: null
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Navigation user={this.state.authUser} />

          ...

          <Route path='/auth' exact render={() => this.state.authUser ? <Redirect to='/status'/> : <Login authUser={this.state.authUser} login={this.login}/> }/>

          ...

          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Login.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.login}><i className="fab fa-google"></i> Sign In with Google</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong.  I'm pretty sure I'm passing things between parent and child incorrectly.  I've tried different methods with bind both in the constructor and when passing to the child.

Comment: It should be `onClick = {this.props.login}` in Login component.

Answer (score 2):

Your passing login as a prop, you should also access it as a prop.

onClick should access it as this.props.login

```
<button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.props.login}><i className="fab fa-google"></i> Sign In with Google</button>
```

Comment: I spent so long trying to figure it out, now I want to slap myself.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in Login.jsx it should be this.props.login

Answer (score -1):

Change your App.js Login line as

```
<Login authUser={this.state.authUser} login={this.login.bind(this)}/> }/>
```

and in Login.jsx

```
<button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.props.login.bind(this)}><i className="fab fa-google"></i> Sign In with Google</button>
```

and do this

```
login = () => {
let x = this;
auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
  .then( (result) => {
    const user = result.user;
    x.setState({
      authUser: user
    });
  })
  .catch( (err) => {
    console.log('Error Logging In', err);
  });
 }
```

Comment: The bind() call should not be necessary and in fact might give undesired results since the login function most likely requires using the parent component's context.

Comment: If there is no bind then the 'this' in login is undefined

Comment: My understanding is that fat arrow functions automatically inherit `this` from its enclosing class. If this isn't true, only the first bind is necessary. The second bind can be removed and the `login()` function can remain as in the OP.